# yarn install within Docker Container giving "self signed certificate in certificate chain"

Tags: reactjs, docker, ca, self-signed-certificate, yarnpkg-v2

To get `docker` and `yarn` working on my corporate network, I needed to add a CA certificate to trust store (for docker) and `set NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS` for `yarn` (see [here](https://github.com/nodejs/corepack/issues/67#issuecomment-1169546096)). The `Dockerfile` for my react application includes `yarn install && yarn run build` which gives a "self signed certificate in certificate chain" error. I am able to get around the error by running `yarn install` on my local machine before building in docker, remove `yarn install` from my `Dockerfile` and remove `node_modules` from my `.dockerignore` file.

How should I be resolving this error? Should I be transferring the `.pem` CA file to the Docker container and adding `set NODE_EXTRA_CA_CERTS` to the `Dockerfile`?

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:15.13-alpine
WORKDIR /react
COPY . .
# RUN yarn config set cafile ./
RUN yarn install && yarn run build
```

`.dockerignore`:

```
node_modules
build
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue on my corporate network. What worked for me is copying the certificate into the image and allow the OS to recognize it by updating CA certificates.

I added this in my Dockerfile:

```
# Copy SSL certificates into the image
COPY *.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/

# Update the certificate stores
RUN update-ca-certificates --verbose --fresh && \
    npm config set cafile /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/my-custom-root-certificate.crt && \
    yarn config set cafile /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/my-custom-root-certificate.crt
```

The `*.crt` files are in my docker build context (or same level as my Dockerfile)